# Testing with Visual Studio Test 2010

Tags: c++, testing

Does any one know if I can test native code in VS Test 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not according to the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171.aspx).

> You cannot have test projects with
>   unit tests that use unmanaged C++.

This is confirmed by MSFT [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/51f82227-1bac-426c-b57b-1bdd0e68a434).

Answer (score 1):

you  can find [here](http://codebasequality.com/?p=42) an interesting way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There was another question here on the stack that I can't find, but it linked me off to 
[How Do I: Create and Run Unit Tests in Visual C++?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fxl7zMzfFM)

This shows that you can unit test native code including C++ but to do so you would still write the unit tests in managed code.

I have not tried this in person, and one thing I noticed was the demo used the COM interface to test the C++ native code, so have no specific experience of using C++ classes more directly in the unit test.